# What is the difference between 'secretive' and 'stealthy'? Can someone please cite some example to get it cleared?

Tags: meaning, differences

To me it seems that being secretive has more to do with speech and behaviour while being stealthy means you're up for something potentially wrong or illegal. I need to have a more clear cut understanding of these two words.

Comment: "Stealthy" generally implies sneaking around, literally or figuratively.

Answer (score 1):

Secretive is about having or keeping something a secret. Being stealthy is about moving around without making noise or being noticed. Moving with stealth.

The cook would not disclose his recipe. He was very secretive when he made it so no one would see his process. My friend tried to find out what it was by creeping into the kitchen stealthily to spy on him. He did not succeed in his attempt due to an unexpected sauce pan.

Stealthy often applies to animals (predators) trying to sneak up on their prey. The word used for people makes them seem more animal like and less human for dramatic purposes.

Comment: Yes, being secretive is usually the motive for being stealthy (the other usual motive is to avoid disturbing someone such as a sleeping child) but it is possible to be secretive without being stealthy. You can just use strong physical locks on your filing cabinets or good password protection on your electronic files